# Changing Eclipse shortcut for Quit in Mac OS X?

Tags: eclipse, macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Like other Mac OS X applications, Eclipse has a shortcut to quit itself, <kbd>Cmd+Q</kbd>. Although this provides a consistent UX, it's very annoying. Since one of the most frequently used shortcut is `Cmd+1`, which is for quick-fix, <kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>Q</kbd> are located too close, and I mistakenly hit <kbd>Cmd+Q</kbd> instead of <kbd>Cmd+1</kbd> very often. And this makes me crazy.

I tried to find the binding in `Preferences Dialog > General > Keys` to change the shortcut, however, I couldn't.

Is there any way to change the shortcut for Quit Eclipse to other keystroke? Or any tip for avoid this inconvenience?

In Chrome, there's an option to prevent this kind of mistake. By enabling `Warn Before Quitting`, we have to hit <kbd>Cmd+Q</kbd> twice to quit the browser. I think this is cool. How can I introduce similar feature to Eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it is possible to change OSX shortcuts from the System Preferences panel:

Go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts. Then click the + button. Choose 'eclipse' as your application (it might be possible that you have to search for the application in "Other..."). The menu title has to be exactly "Quit Eclipse" and enter a new shortcut. Click add, and you're all set.

If you have any more questions, please shoot :)

[image: Change shortcut in System Preferences]

[image: New Eclipse Menu]

Comment: Since there were no answers for a long time, I thought there were no ways to do this. Your answer will greatly helped me. Thank you very much.